# Panel data with Sector year fixed effects on R

Tags: econometrics, applied-econometrics, paneldata, data, fixed-effects

I am trying to replicate the following econometric equation from the paper "How do french manufacturing firms react to Energy shocks ?"
[image]

s denotes sectors,i denotes firms, and t denotes year.
The paper uses panel data. As you see it has $\phi_i$ **for firms fixed effects**. I know how to implement such in R, I would use the following code:

```
model1 <- plm(log(Panel$Prices)~ log(Panel$Electricity.pricr)+log(Panel$Gaz.Price)+
          data=Panel, index= c("Secteur","Date"), model="within",effect= "individual")
```

The command effect= "individual" enables me to have firm fixed effect.

However the paper includes also **sector-year fixed effects $\chi_{st}$**. But I do not know how to implement a fixed effect that plays on two variable at the same time: s and t. Do you know how I could implement it in R ?

Thank you

Comment: ``interaction(secteur, year)`` seems to do the job. It generates a factor. You can add it as a regressor.

Comment: Thank you, but how would you write that piece of code ?

Comment: ``model1 <- plm(log(Panel$Prices)~ log(Panel$Electricity.pricr)+log(Panel$Gaz.Price)+ interaction(Secteur, year),
          data=Panel, index= c("Secteur","Date"), model="within",effect= "individual")``

Comment: Assuming you have a `year` variable

Comment: Do you have a complete reference of the paper (maybe a link)? It is not possible to find it easily.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sketch of the code:

1. Concatenate the sector and year, so it reads as "energy1987" or so.  They should be unique.
2. Encode this concatenated vector as a collection of binary dummies.
3. Use this set of dummies in the regression.

But given a choice about reinventing the wheel, use the existing tools.

Comment: Would it work just by adding +Panel$Date * Panel$Secteur in the regressor like this ? :  plm(log(Panel$Prices)~ log(Panel$Electricity.price)+log(Panel$Gaz.Price)+ Panel$Date * Panel$Sector,  data=Panel, index= c("Sector","Date"), model="within",effect= "individual")